# Select all tables in psql database EXCEPT those matching [pattern]

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a database with many tables that are used as a reference for valid values in the other tables. These reference tables are all named `valid[table]`, so I can display them in psql with `\dt valid*`.

I'd like to be able to select all the *non*-reference tables (which are more variably named, but none of them start with `valid`), but can't figure out how. I've tried various things like `\dt !valid*` , `\dt !~valid*` , `\dt NOT LIKE 'valid%'`, but these either error or don't find a match.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual, `psql` supports [these patterns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS). Normally you could use regular expression negative lookahead `(?!valid)*` but `?` cannot be used in regular expression with `psql` because it is translated to `.`. It is probably easier to do a query from `INFROMATION SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') --exclude system tables
    AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' -- only tables
    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'valid%';
```

Comment: Thanks Simo, that works perfectly! I didn't know you could access an information schema like that, very cool.