# How can I match all tables except one using --exclude-table-data flag in pg_dump?

Tags: regex, postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I'm using `psql` 13.4 to make a `pg_dump` of a database. I need only the schema (no data) for all tables except one enumerated reference table, for which I need the data. I see that `pg_dump` has an `--exclude-table-data` flag that supports regex patterns. But it does not have an `--include-table-data` flag.

So to exclude table data for all tables except the single reference table, I thought I could use a regex with negative look ahead. For example this one: `^(?!.*(reference_table_name))`. However this doesn't seem to work due to psql's special character limitations (e.g. on `*`, `?`, and `.`) described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS). I've tried to make the substitutions it suggests but it doesn't work.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, this actually *can* be done with the restricted regular expressions available in this context – but whether you’d want to actually do this is another matter, because pretty it ain’t.

Namely, to exclude the data of all tables except `sometable`, you have to write this:

```
(|[^s]*|s(|[^o]*|o(|[^m]*|m(|[^e]*|e(|[^t]*|t(|[^a]*|a(|[^b]*|b(|[^l]*|l(|[^e]*|e?*)))))))))
```

How does this monstrosity come about? The key to understand it is that it is a composition of copies of the following basic pattern:

```
(|[^s]*|s*)
```

This alternation will match one of the following:

- nothing
- any character except “s”, followed by anything (let’s call this the negative case)
- the character “s”, followed by anything (the positive case)

So by itself, this construct is equivalent to `*` and just matches anything. However, by separating the cases, it creates a hook for conditions to be added to any of them. (Any mathematicians reading this should instantly recognize this move.)

Now let’s vary the the positive case slightly:

```
(|[^e]*|e?*)
```

Now, the positive case matches the character “e” *only* if followed by at least one more character. So this pattern will match *almost* anything: anything except the string `e`.

Now we take two of these patterns, one of each:

```
(|[^l]*|l*)
(|[^e]*|e?*)
```

… and we restrict the positive case of the first pattern by replacing its `*` with the second pattern, i.e. we take “an ‘l’ followed by anything” and replace “anything” with “anything except just an ‘e’”:

```
(|[^l]*|l(|[^e]*|e?*))
```

So now we have a pattern which will, in total, match one the following things:

- nothing
- any character except “l”, followed by anything
- the character “l”, followed by nothing
- the character “l”, then any character except “e”, followed by anything
- the characters “l” then “e”, followed by at least one more character

… which means this pattern matches any string except `le`.

Now we iterate by taking another instance of the basic pattern:

```
(|[^b]*|b*)
(|[^l]*|l(|[^e]*|e?*))
```

… and repeating the same substitution:

```
(|[^b]*|b(|[^l]*|l(|[^e]*|e?*)))
```

By the same token as previously, this matches any string except `ble`.

So. Let’s start over with a whole series of copies of the same pattern:

```
(|[^s]*|s*)
(|[^o]*|o*)
(|[^m]*|m*)
(|[^e]*|e*)
(|[^t]*|t*)
(|[^a]*|a*)
(|[^b]*|b*)
(|[^l]*|l*)
(|[^e]*|e?*)
```

Folding these together yields the pattern I gave at the start – which therefore is a pattern that matches any string except `sometable`.

This is how you *can* do it. It’s up to you whether you’d actually *want* to. Maybe putting a link to this answer in a comment next to the code will make it more justifiable…

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to exclude data from tables in the dump except one using the `--exclude-table-data` parameter with different variants of the regular expression, but as you point to the restriction with the `?` character, it seems even according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29232803/2754392 that this is not possible.